# Injecting EJB, PersistenceContext into @Stateless Jersey Resource

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, jersey, jersey-2.0

Neither @PersistenceContext nor @EJB are injected into my EJB Jersey resource. I can access my JAX-RS endpoints. Can Jersey not access the built-in JPA provider (Hibernate)?

I have a simple WAR deployed to JBoss EAP 6.2 (AS 7.2.2). I have removed the built-in RESTEasy libs from JBoss and packaged Jersey 2.10.1 with my application. I have included the latest Jersey 2 release in my `pom.xml`. This is my only declared dependency.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have a `@Stateless` JAX-RS resource which is correctly served by Jersey.

```
@Stateless
@Path("generic")
@LocalBean
public class GenericResource {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TestWebAppPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String get() {
        // em is null here
        // ...
```

As you might guess from the code comment, the EntityManager is not injected. In other tests, I also see that @PersistenceUnit and @EJB do not get injected.

I have no web.xml and my JAX-RS Application class is a simple extends from `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig` with no content. It does have the @ApplicationPath annotation.

I do know that JPA and the persistence unit are correctly working in the WAR in general. I have a timer EJB that runs and correctly can use an injected EntityManager. It's only within the Jersey resource that things are not injected.

I suppose the problem is related to dependencies because I'm running on JBoss or maybe my JAX-RS Application class is incomplete somehow. I have been banging my head on the desk for 3 days (while learning a lot in the process!) so I really appreciate assistance.

---

Previously I thought the log message at Jersey startup that Jersey cannot find the method `javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.value()` was a good clue. After poking through the Jersey code it seems this really isn't important.

Comment: I've confirmed the exact WAR works correctly in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and the EntityManager is injected as expected. So it's just not working with JBoss EAP 6.2 (nor 6.1)

Comment: I have given up on this path. I was never able to get my resources injected into Jersey within EAP. Instead, I migrated to RESTEasy which works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no `web.xml` descriptor so no servlet adaptor to serve you resources, you may need to use the JAX-RS alternative, which is providing an `ApplicationPath`:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("application")
public class RestApplication extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {
...  
}
```

You may need to override the `getClasses` and `getSingletons` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do have that annotation though (and edited my question accordingly). I can get into the URI (i.e., GET works) but the EntityManager is just not injected

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using EJBs or CDI you should use the EntityManager from EJBs/CDI but not from the RS resource. Ofcourse it is just an architectural suggestion.

As far as having the resources injected in to your jersey components I do have trouble with the CDI and injection with jersey and jboss. For now I'm using a workaround and still trying to figure out how to get CDI working.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class CDIBeanManagerImpl {

@Override
public void destroyRequestContext() {
    //CreationalContext is handled by a containter
}

@Override
public <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) {
    BeanManager beanManager = null;
    try {
        beanManager = (BeanManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not look up BeanManager", ex);
    }
    Bean<?> bean = beanManager.resolve(beanManager.getBeans(clazz));
    if (bean == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return (T) beanManager.getReference(bean, clazz, beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));
}

@Override
public <T> Set<T> getBeans(Class<T> clazz) {
    BeanManager beanManager = null;
    try {
        beanManager = (BeanManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not look up BeanManager", ex);
    }
    Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(clazz);
    Set<T> instances = new HashSet<T>();
    for (Bean<?> bean : beans) {
        CreationalContext<?> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
        T instance = (T) beanManager.getReference(bean, clazz, creationalContext);
        instances.add(instance);
    }
    return instances;
}

@Override
public void initRequestContext() {
    //CreationalContext is handled by a containter
}

@Override
public Object newJNDIInstance(String jndiName) {
    try {
        //Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(jndiName.substring(jndiName.indexOf("!") + 1));
        //return getBean(clazz);
        return new InitialContext().lookup(jndiName);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

}

The first two methods are used for looking up beans that uses CDI and last method is used for looking up an EJB.